# Heroku supports ruby 2.2.0 but looks for 2.1.x and fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to deploy my rails (4.1.5) app onto heroku (Cedar stack). The page with [supported ruby versions on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions) lists 2.2.0 as supported.

I have 2.2.0 as my active global version in rbenv, and there is no local version specified.

My Gemfile contains `ruby '2.2.0'` as required by Heroku.

When I call `git push heroku master`, it fails with the following error:

```
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote:  !
remote:  !     An error occurred while installing Ruby ruby-2.1.2-p95
remote:  !     For supported Ruby versions see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote:  !     Note: Only the most recent version of Ruby 2.1 is supported on Cedar-14
remote:  !     Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl --fail --retry 3 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/cedar-14/ruby-2.1.2-p95.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed unexpectedly:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
remote:  !     tar: Child returned status 1
remote:  !     tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

This seems to indicate that heroku is trying to install the older version of ruby on my machine (ruby-2.1.2-p95) and failing, since it is not a supported version. How can I fix this?

Comment: post your gemfile and your gemfile.lock also what SO are you running

Comment: Are you sure the actual Gemfile being pushed has 2.2.0?  Smells like you aren't merged w/master and are pushing something other than what you think.

Comment: Yes, @NickVeys you are right. I hadn't committed that ruby version change. That worked! Thanks.